# Who's the guy in the snow-speeder?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

These set photos and concept art images were [released by Disney](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awkens-deleted-scenes/4/) to highlight a number of scenes that were deleted from the film, notably the "Snowspeeder Chase" scene that was trimmed to bring the film down from a leg-cramp-inducing 3 hours.

In the novelisation and script, the speeder contains Rey **and Finn**. I was intrigued to see that her companion is a wiry looking white guy. Is this still supposed to be Finn (or perhaps his stunt double or stand-in) or is it a different character entirely?

[image]

Comment: There's a couple of interviews [here](http://bgr.com/2016/01/01/star-wars-force-awakens-deleted-scenes/) about the deleted scenes; I haven't watched them, but it's possible they might touch on this.

Comment: @randal'thor - Not that I could see. They talk about which scenes they liked, but not a lot beyond that.

Comment: Stunt double??? Random production crew guy pretending to be an action hero? Finn using the force to throw off First Order?

Comment: @DVK - Ironically, Random Production Crew Guy now has his own page on Wookieepedia and an EU novel in the works.

Comment: is there any infos if those scenes are going to be included in the blue ray version? I mean if it is 3 hours originally we are talking about TWENTY FIVE minutes of deleted scenes oO

Comment: @Thomas - No info is out yet, but I'd be astounded if they didn't include some of it. The cynic in me says that they almost certainly cut it in order to include it layer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any reason to believe that character is anyone else other than Finn, other than the concept art shows him as not being dark skinned. It was likely created before the casting of John Boyega.

**Update:**

I just watched the movie again. When Rey and Finn start to climb the outside of the giant regulator building you actually see a quick glimpse of the snow-speeder they must have just used.

You can see where the deleted scene likely was. Han and Chewie enter the building, and then Rey and Finn are *somewhere* and manage to trigger all the doors to open. Next we see Rey and Finn outside the building (next to the snow-speeder) starting to climb. For some reason they needed to go somewhere else to open those doors, and then likely had a hectic race back to help Han and Chewie.

**End Update**

> Boyega, who was born in London to Nigerian parents, went through seven months of auditions before being told he had the role and when it was announced he was the recipient of some racist internet bullying. But he responded by posting a message on Instagram telling those who thought there couldn't be a black stormtrooper to "get used to it." - [telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/daisy-ridley-john-boyega-interview-rey-finn/)

Unless you believe the top and right images are actual footage.

Comment: I can't believed I managed to misread that as Finn being a Nigerian stormtrooper taken from London for 7 months of training

Comment: “A black stormtrooper” is not a new development for Star Wars.  “A stormtrooper with any human race at all” is the new development.  The originals were carefully crafted to never show the people inside the stormtrooper suits— they could've been all black all along as far as a naive moviegoer knows.  The prequels have clones of the same pacific-islander guy, but IIRC most of them die before the transition to stormtrooperism.

Comment: Star Wars Rebels is canon, that revealed that storm troopers were, humans, not clones, and not all white. This was before we knew Boyega was cast as a stormtrooper. .