# When do we see Poe Dameron on a speeder?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, merchandise, poe-dameron

I recently saw this toy in a superstore near where I work.

[image: Poe Dameron speeder]

[Link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B013R0HI86) to Amazon product.

When do we see Poe on a speeder? Is it in a deleted scene? Or is it from one of the novels?

Comment: Maybe the guy in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113767/whos-the-guy-in-the-snow-speeder) was Poe rather than an earlier version of Finn? :-P

Comment: @rand the box says it was specifically designed/modified for the desert.

Comment: I remember mentions of a book/comic in one of my questions, which covers the escape from Jakku from Poe's point of view. He was dazed due to the crash and thus lost his way while searching for Finn & then BB-8. Eventually he recovered his senses enough to make his way near enough to witness the First Order attack from afar. After confirming that BB-8's tracking signal escaped to space, though, he decided to call in Resistance SpecForce for extraction from further Imperial entanglements. Maybe the speeder would be from this last part? I'd post this as an answer but idk the exact source...

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Nah, this (and the desert speeder and the camo assault walker) are simply modified vehicles that were never in the film.

Answer (score 7):

There's a [deleted scene after the crash on Jakku](http://www.denofgeek.us/movies/star-wars/251904/star-wars-the-force-awakens-what-deleted-scenes-might-we-see), where Poe used a speeder. The scene is in the novelization of TFA

> In the book, Foster describes Poe scrambling from the wreckage of the Tie-Fighter in a daze and, in the process, accidentally leaving his jacket behind in the pilot's seat. Stranded in the desert, Poe meets a speeder-driving scavenger with “mirrored eyeshades [...] wide snout, and a toothy grin."
>
> During the chase, Poe again shows off his prowess as a pilot by taking control of the speeder and thwarting the clan’s pursuit.

This isn't the only [TFA toy without an actual movie scene](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125351/when-do-we-see-a-assault-walker-in-the-force-awakens), either

Comment: The speeder described in the novel sounds nothing like the one in that box, but I'll still give this a +1 since it involves Poe in close proximity to a speeder on Jakku.

Comment: @Richard The jacket doesn't fit either (we know it winds up with Finn). My bet is the discrepancy has to do with the process of making toys like this vs making a movie. Hasbro was almost certainly given the design more than a year in advance, when this scene was probably still nothing more than a storyboard (perhaps filmed but no CG added). So someone was probably tasked with providing Hasbro a workable speeder design (that hadn't been finalized by the art dept) and they just "modernized" a ROTJ speeder.