# When do we see a Assault Walker in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, stormtroopers, merchandise

I recently saw this toy in a superstore near where I work.

[image: Assault Walker]

[Link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B013R0HI86) to Amazon product.

When do we see an Assault walker ? Is it in the assault on

> Maz's castle?

The packaging left me with the impression that this was related to the force awakens

Comment: Wookieepedia reports that they're only found in merchandising, not in the film; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mobile_assault_walker

Comment: There's other vehicles in the same range that are also absent from the filn; http://www.argos.co.uk/v1/static/Product/partNumber/4154567.htm

Comment: @Richard that link doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: I'm not sure during the Empire era, but they use them a fair bit in the Clone wars Tv series. Can't remember the episode though.

Comment: See also this toy that doesn't feature in the movie: http://www.ew.com/article/2016/04/15/constable-zuvio-star-wars-force-awakens

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Works fine for me. Try this one instead; http://www.walmart.com/ip/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens-3.75-Vehicle-Jakku-Landspeeder/45057834

Comment: @Richard I never knew this, merchandise characters cut from films, was so rampant!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - What's more annoying is that Hasbro doubled up on Finn dolls (even going so far as to give him vehicles that he never came into contact with) while at the same time producing hardly any Rey dolls because *"girls don't buy action figures"*

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that the walker appears anywhere in the movie itself. The assault on Maz's castle had troop transports and TIE fighters, but no walkers (they would have been a poor choice given the hilly terrain and nearby lake). It could have been planned (these were released well before the movie itself) but dropped in the final cut. The scene where I would have expected to see them would have been the First Order firing of Starkiller Base (where we see a new type of AT-AT on the far right)

[image]

It could be that these walkers are parked next to these and you can't see them due to the TIE fighters parked in front. It would make sense that they still exist, given their predecessor's [use in the Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Recon_Transport)

[image]