# Does the First Order's "Heavy Scout Walker" / "AT-HS" exist in any official fiction (besides Lego sets)?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, vehicles, toys

The "First Order Heavy Scout Walker" [Lego set](https://www.lego.com/en-us/starwars/products/first-order-heavy-scout-walker-75177) depicts this multi-legged vehicle participating in the battle on Crait from *The Last Jedi*:

[image]

But this does not seem to match the events of the movie, and I don't recall seeing this vehicle on Crait at all.

I'd considered that it may be one of the vehicles seen

> pulling the battering ram cannon,

but [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176487/do-we-know-the-names-of-the-vehicles-ships-seen-in-the-last-jedi#176489) identifies those as the "AT-HH" / "All-Terrain Heavy Hauler".

According to Wookieepedia, the Last Jedi Visual Dictionary designates it as the "AT-HS" / "All-Terrain Heavy Scout", but as I don't have a copy of the book, I can't confirm this.

So, what is this vehicle, actually? Was it cut from the film? Was it designed for the film, but left unused in the production process? Was it merely designed to provide a mid-sized vehicle for toys and Lego sets? And regardless of its origins, has it appeared in any Star Wars fiction outside of The Last Jedi?

Comment: I don't have the Visual Dictionary yet, but it shows up twice in *The Art of Star Wars The Last Jedi*, but offers no real insight.

Comment: @phantom42 Sheesh, I think an art & design book should at least include information on whether things were originally intended to appear in the film or not...

Comment: Well, everything is always designed with the idea that it may get used. It's a matter of how early it was designed, and for what purpose - what was the thought behind it? One of the images shows the vehicle in a hangar on the dreadnought. The other shows it on Crait alongside a ram vehicle. Neither of the images even reference the walker, focusing on the rest of the images.

Answer (score 8):

In the same way that [this walker was cut from *The Force Awakens*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125351/when-do-we-see-a-assault-walker-in-the-force-awakens), this toy was probably from a planned scene that was deleted or altered. Keep in mind that the books and toys have to be planned out months or years in advance to sync up demand with the movie's release, and cannot be changed easily just because of script changes or editing. Note the toy's description

> Go in search of Resistance fighters in the amazing First Order Heavy Scout Walker. Place General Hux in the cockpit and send orders to the Flametrooper. Give the walker a push and see the crawling legs start to move! When you spot the enemy, raise the spring-loaded shooters and get ready to fire!

The problem here is that General Hux is on Kylo Ren's shuttle, not on the ground or in a walker. We also never see Flametroopers in the movie. There was probably a larger battle that got cut for Luke's solo act.

The *Star Wars Visual Dictionary* page mentioning AT-HHs and AT-M6s only mentions the AT-HS model number and full name. It has no images or description.
[image]

Comment: We do see flame troopers enter the base in the very end of the movie, they have the same helmet, but we don't see them use their weapons.

Comment: Wow, now I really wonder what the AT-PD was meant to look like. Something roughly human-sized, like an Imperial probe droid, but walking instead of hovering?

Answer (score 7):

It actually does have a real picture on Crait that must have been cut from the movie. It's shown in the background of a picture of the superlaser siege cannon in *[The Art of Star Wars, The Last Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi)*, a book that had a bunch of concept artwork in it.

[image: The AT-HS in concept artwork]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing the picture with one that's from a scan. You might want to note that this is clearly a concept art rendering, not a scene from the actual movie.