# What Star Wars toys didn't make the final cut of the movie?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Inspired by this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176951/does-the-first-orders-heavy-scout-walker-at-hs-exist-in-any-official-fict), I wonder what other Lego sets or toys were put in the production pipeline only to have their on-screen appearance left on the editing floor.

Obviously, there is the AT-HS...what else?

Comment: This may be a tricky one, as ever since the Mini-Rigs: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mini-Rig They've been occasionally designing things purely for the toys, without any intent of using them in a film, TV series, etc.

Comment: I would say that those do NOT fall within the purview of the question - I'm looking for the particular circumstance where plans changed along the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Fully deleted appearances

### Jedi Temple analysis droids

In *Attack of the Clones*, a scene where Obi-Wan brings the Kaminoan dart to analysis droids at the Jedi Temple was cut, but the droids' action figures were still released alongside the film:

[image: Droid action figures]
[image: Deleted scene screenshot of a droid]

<sub>(Image credit: https://www.planetdiecast.com/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=16481&category_id=211)</sub>

## Mostly deleted appearances

If we widen the definition a little to include background characters and vehicles, there are some honorable mentions:

### Shaak Ti

An action figure of Shaak Ti released alongside Revenge of the Sith, but her most prominent scene in the film, in which she is killed by General Grievous, was cut and declared non-canonical. She still briefly appears in the final film as a hologram, but not in person as depicted in the action figure.

[image: Photo of Shaak Ti action figure]
<sub>(Image credit: https://farpointtoys.com/products/star-wars-revenge-of-the-sith-shaak-ti-21-jedi-master-action-figure-hasbro)</sub>

### Constable Zuvio

Probably the best-known case, the mysterious "Constable Zuvio" was one of the first action figures released for *The Force Awakens*, but only appears in a handful of frames in the background of the final film:

[image: Constable Zuvio action figure] [image: Blurry screenshot of Constable Zuvio in the background]

<sub>(Image credit: https://www.lulu-berlu.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-constable-zuvio-a40042-en.html; https://thepopinsider.com/features/columns/legend-of-zuvio-episodes-viii/)</sub>

### First Order Snowspeeder

Similarly, the First Order Snowspeeder appears in the background of the finished film, but was originally the subject of a longer action scene:

[image: Deleted scene screenshot of Finn and Rey in a First Order snowspeeder]

> The First Order snowspeeder is briefly seen in #TheForceAwakens and more prominently featured in a deleted chase sequence. Doug’s design here is fairly close to the finished vehicle, which ended up a two-seater by story necessity. #StarWars
>
> <sub>—@PhilSzostak; https://twitter.com/PhilSzostak/status/1226291825209561088</sub>

It had action figures and Lego models based on it at the launch of *The Force Awakens*, though crewed by stormtroopers rather than Finn and Rey:

[image: Action figure vehicle version of the First Order Snowspeeder in front of its box]
<sub>(Image credit: https://futureofstarwars.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/review-first-order-snowspeeder-from-the-force-awakens/)</sub>

Comment: I wonder whether the Lego Sand Speeder (basically the Snow Speeder in tan with some minor elements changed) counts - Im not sure it was ever planned to be in any of the films, but Lego released one anyway.

Comment: @Moo I think that would fall into the same category as the Mini-Rigs the asker mentioned they weren't looking for, since it was based on a canceled Kenner toy rather than any movie scenes. There are a few other Lego-only Star Wars vehicles (eg https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Dropship), but as far as I know, the AT-HS is the only one originally intended to launch alongside one of the films.

Comment: What does this mean "the Kaminoan dart to analysis droids"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I interpret the sentence as he brought a "dart" (weapon or slang?) made by (or otherwise associated with) the Kaminoans (alien species or nation?) to be analyzed by the analysis droids.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis thanks, makes sense. I get now that the toy figures are the "analysis droids".